# Error when set android:installLocation="preferExternal"

Tags: android, installation, adb

when I set the Manifest.xml file like this

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.fugo.Rocket"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0"
  android:installLocation="preferExternal">
```

the android installation will get error

> > [2011-03-24 18:18:47 - Rocket Project] Installation error:
> >     INSTALL_FAILED_CONTAINER_ERROR
> >     [2011-03-24 18:18:47 - Rocket Project]
> >     Please check logcat output for more
> >     details. [2011-03-24 18:18:47 - Rocket
> >     Project] Launch canceled!

but when I set android:intallLocation="auto"

the installation is success. why is that?

logcat Error

> 03-24 18:48:38.784:
>   ERROR/PackageHelper(1284): Failed to
>   create secure container smdl2tmp1
>   03-24 18:48:38.784:
>   ERROR/DefContainer(1284): Failed to
>   create container smdl2tmp1 03-24
>   18:48:38.784: ERROR/Vold(86): ASEC
>   file '/mnt/secure/asec/smdl2tmp1.asec'
>   currently exists - destroy it first!
>   (Address already in use)

Comment: Could you provide the logcat detail? You can get it from the adb tool, Eclipse in Debug view or with the "aLogCat" app available in the Market.

Comment: 03-24 18:48:38.784: ERROR/PackageHelper(1284): Failed to create secure container smdl2tmp1

03-24 18:48:38.784: ERROR/DefContainer(1284): Failed to create container smdl2tmp1

03-24 18:48:38.784: ERROR/Vold(86): ASEC file '/mnt/secure/asec/smdl2tmp1.asec' currently exists - destroy it first! (Address already in use)

Comment: Is this on the emulator?

Comment: Are you able to try mounting a clean SD card? Otherwise you can try to delete the 'smdl2tmp1.asec' file.

Comment: rightly. deleting that file finish my problem. :)

Comment: I had this problem and setting android:intallLocation="auto" solved it.  I never was able to find smdl2tmp1.asec to delete it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check what your minSDKversion is set to. This feature is available only from FROYO. (SDK VERSION 8 onwards).

Also you need to compile this and run on Android2.2 sdk

Comment: Worth noting that while the feature is only avaliable from SDK level 8 onwards, it will still run on lower versions and simply ignore the XML.

Comment: To compile it, you should set your target to >=8 and may leave minSDKversion <8

Comment: There are several variations on the `Failed to create container smdl2tmp1` problem, for some of them see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30343659/313113

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the file smdl2tmp1.asec was somehow corrupted. I put the card on the PC and I was not even able to copy that file into my harddisk (for backup). So I had to delete it, and it solved the problem.

Yesterday my phone rebooted while installing a game, and I think it has somehitng to do with this problem.

Answer (score 2):

It appears Android is a little buggy in this respect, and does not handle all possible cases correctly.

I had a similar, but more complicated problem. The solution is basically to delete the appropriate file in /sdcard/.android_secure/...  See also:

http://www.androidpolice.com/2011/04/19/fixing-the-couldnt-install-on-usb-storage-or-sd-card-problem-on-android/

My own problem involved *two* android devices. One app was installed on device#1 (Android 2.2), then I mounted device#1 onto device#2 (an Android 4.0.3).  Then I installed the same app on device#2. Guess what, it installed onto the SD card of device#1, *overwriting* the install on device#1.  The app did not work on device#2 after unmounting device#1.  The app did still work on device#1.   I uninstalled it on device#2, no errors, but could not re-install it (I got the error "Failed to create secure container smdl2tmp1").

My solution was to uninstall the app on device#1, then re-mount it onto device#2, then installing it on device#2 worked.  Then I moved the app from SD card to internal memory.

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest that you check and see if you have an external SD card mounted from your emulator?  You can set it when you create your AVD.

Answer (score 0):

Rebooting the device worked for me.