# Getting application could not be installed while updating android application

Tags: android, android-studio

I tried installing new version (2.0) of the my  app when the previous APP (1.0) is installed. But it fails to get updated. The new version gets installed when the previous version is not installed.

Comment: What's the error message? Did you use a different key to sign the versions?

Comment: How are you installing the app?

Comment: No I'm not building a signed apk.

Comment: An app is always signed. If you don't do it yourself, an automatically generated debug key is used. This key is different for each installation of Android Studio.

Comment: I'm using Android studio 2.2.3 for app  V2.0 and for  V1.0  we used different version of android studio, does this matter?

Answer (score 0):

I think you installed your previous app with unsigned apk or without instant run feature, and new app with signed apk or with instant run feature. 
Check it. Instant run sometimes not make correct apk so Goto Build->Build APK and make apk and install it again.

Comment: No I'm not building a signed apk

Answer (score 0):

when you install the new version of the app the problem should be,

1. old and new app have different Signed Certificate
2. New APK have small version code then installed

See this link to Know more [Error Creating Image File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30276876/error-creating-imagefile-read-only-file-system/30343659#30343659)