# Internal Storage seems not to be set, how to solve this?

Tags: android, adb

I cannot install any apps and the installed apps have your data cache as 0kb at settings. When I try to install an app, the "adb logcat" return this:

ActivityManager: Unable to start service Intent < cmp=com.android.defcontainer/.DefaultContainerService > U=0: not found
PackageManager: Failed to bind to media container service
InstallAppProgress: Installtion error code: 1

None of the solutions at [Error creating imagefile (Read-only file system)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30276876/error-creating-imagefile-read-only-file-system/30343659#30343659) have success. It's as the internal storage of 4Gb of the device is recognized, and the few files of the internal storage is mounted at /sdcard, but dont have any sdcard plugged in it.

"adb shell sm list-disks" return none;

"adb shell sm list-volumes all" return:

private mounted null
emulated mounted null

"adb shell sm-get-primary-storage-uuid" return "null"

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Android studio 3.3 you can go to view => Tools Window => Device file explorer. That would show you the device files. Please note that if you are using a Samsung phone for debugging,

If you have a SAMSUNG device, don't bother - SAMSUNG broke run-as by dropping the setuid flag (so run-as has no chance of switching to a different identity).

Also don't bother trying the Smart Switch "reinitialize device" workaround, it won't work until SAMSUNG fixes it in the firmware (so it is worth updating to the latest version).

Use some other method to access your app's data, like adb backup:

adb backup -f data.ab dd if=data.ab bs=24 skip=1 | openssl zlib -d > data.tar

please see [run-as: Could not set capabilities: Operation not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37413667/run-as-could-not-set-capabilities-operation-not-permitted)

Comment: It's not a Samsung device, it's a MXQ 4k tv box. I dont have the Android Studio, but i'll look at this.